Why is a program os dependent?
I understand that processors belonging to different architectures have different instruction set and therefore a program compiled for one processor(hardware platform) can't run on a processor with different ISA. 
But why is a compiled program OS dependent?
For example a C program compiled on windows OS running on a x86 intel processor doesn't run on linux OS running on the same x86 intel processor.
What happens during compilation that makes the executable dependent on OS?
For example does gcc do something different that msvc during compilation in the case of c?
I have read a related question but couldn't find a deep and satisfying answer.

Please don't cross-post: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/170816/6729.

First, the executable file isn't just raw code; it's nearly always in some structured format which describes which section is to be mapped as executable code ('text'), which section is to be mapped as data, where the entry point is in the code, etc. The format isn't universal across every OS; for example, Windows and UEFI use PE/COFF while Linux and FreeBSD use ELF (and macOS uses something else) – so Windows wouldn't recognize the structure of an ELF-format .exe file.
Second, programs don't have direct control of the hardware; they rely on calling the OS for everything from text output to network access to even exiting cleanly (as opposed to letting the instruction pointer run off into unmapped memory). And since every OS provides different system calls (and sometimes uses different calling conventions for those), that makes the compiled program OS-dependent since it is compiled to use the system call conventions of that particular OS.
Most programs also rely on OS-provided libraries, e.g. the C standard library libc is almost always dynamically-loaded from a .so file on Linux, and many programs compiled with MSVC similarly rely on a msvcrt*.dll.
It can be possible to run programs from a different OS, as long as they're provided with the necessary environment. See e.g. what Wine does to allow Windows executables to run on Linux – it has to implement a PE/COFF loader (which also needs to understand how to load .dll libraries as those are structured differently from Linux .so libraries), and it needs to provide a lot of "standard" Windows DLLs (many of which are re-implemented in terms of similar Linux libraries).
(Similarly, FreeBSD has the "Linuxulator" – it implements many Linux system calls directly as part of the FreeBSD kernel. Early Linux used to have binary compatibility with Solaris executables, and some old Unix-like systems used to be cross-compatible to some extent. Even Windows had WSL1 for a short while, and also had an "OS/2 subsystem" back in Windows XP days.)

Programs interact with the operating system and the way a program does that differs per operating system.
For example, if we take Windows as example, when the executable wants to create a window, it will have to use instructions the OS understands in order to create a window at a specific location, and then draw the controls in them.
This part already differs per OS. Another thing to take in mind is how drivers are different for different OSses, and programs may have to interact with drivers. For example, you can't just say: place a pixel on the screen at location x and y. You send this command to the OS and it will interact with the graphics card to make it happen.
There is no universal way to interact with an OS, which is why each OS has its own structure and that's why you can't have a linux binary run natively on windows.
Of course, there are frameworks that you can code in that are cross-platform, but in those cases, while you have one codebase that can compile to all OSses, each OS still gets their own version of the executable.
Don't forget, an application can do anything the OS supports, but not all OSses support the same things.
And before people point out emulation in the comments, I think that takes this answer too far out of context.
